# How to display custom text from the URL on MacOS menu bar?

Tags: macos, mac

I'd like to display my website statistics on MacOS menu bar (status bar). I have created a simple page which displays the statistics as follows `Users online: 10   Today: 3319`. The question is how to put it on my menu bar? It shouldn't be very difficult as this is a simple one line text. Is there any app for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time searching I've at last found somethig that exactly fits my needs. Infinite Menu Bar https://apps.apple.com/us/app/infinite-menu-bar/id1439179659?mt=12 allows to add http response callbacks to menu bar, I can even add more than one callback and place it using standard MacOS functions in required order. It's $3,99 now so not so expensive for such flexibility.